# What is the limit for total number of records in Datatable?

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable

What is the total number of records that can be fetched in a **ADO.NET** data-table?

Comment: Probably (size of your memory / avg. size per row)

Comment: The answer that @psubsee2003 was referring to was deleted, the currently accepted answer should be correct.

Comment: @Chuu thanks for the ping.  I have deleted my comment

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx), the limit is 16,777,216 rows.

Comment: What will happen if the Datatable row exceeds the limit, Any exception will be thrown